Correlation between the derivatives of a real function and the corresponding derivatives of vector function
Let a function $F: [a, a + h] \subseteq \mathbb R^k  \to \mathbb R$ be given. Define a function $\varphi : [0,1] \to \mathbb R^k$ as $\varphi(t) = a + th$ and a composite function $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ as $f(t) = F(\varphi(t))$. Since the derivative of the map $F \circ \varphi$ is a linear map in $\mathbb R$, it can be identified with $f'$. Applying the chain rule we get:
$$f'(t) = F'(\varphi(t)) \circ \varphi'(t)$$
The corresponding matrix of $\phi'(t)$ is the vector $h$, thus we can write:
$$f'(t) = F'(\varphi(t))(h)$$
Is there a way to extend this idea to higher-order derivatieves and find the correspondence between $f^{(n)}$ and $(F \circ \varphi)^{(n)}$, which should be:
$$f^{(n)}(t)=F'(\varphi(t))(h,\dots,h)$$
Is it even possible to calculate derivative of $F'(\varphi(t))(h)$ or $F'(\varphi(t)) \circ \varphi'(t)$?
